# C++ Stack Overflow?

Tags: c++, recursion, stack-overflow

I have written a recursive function (nextMove) that aims to find the way through a maze represented by a 12x12 matrix in a Win 32 console. Unfortunately when I try to run it using Visual Studio, the console session terminates abnormally after a couple of dozen iterations and disappears without giving me any info.

Is this a stack overflow?

It may be that because I am reading in a matrix, defining some variables and calling other functions within nextMove, that this is too much for the stack and knackers it...but I'm not sure.

The recursive function is below: 
(apologies in advance that it won't win any beauty / elegance contests as I am pretty new to programming)

```
void nextMove(char A[size][size], int lRow, int lCol, int cRow, int cCol)
{
    A[lRow][lCol] = '.';
    A[cRow][cCol] = 'X';
    printMatrix(A);
    if (isBorder(cRow, cCol)) { return; }
    else {
        int r, c; // temporary row and col
        int lastMove = move(cRow - lRow, cCol - lCol);
        for (int i = -1; i <= 2; i++) {
            r = cRow + row((lastMove + i) % 4);
            c = cCol + col((lastMove + i) % 4);
            if (allowableMove(A, r, c)) {
                nextMove(A, cRow, cCol, r, c);
                break;
            }
        } // end for
    } // end else
} // end nextMove
```

Comment: Run the program from the command prompt.  that way, the window won't close and you'd be able to see any error that is written out to the console.

Comment: Have you checked to see if it legitimately finished by putting a breakpoint near the end?

Comment: @Zeta, sorry when I try to run it Edited now. Thanks

Comment: @sftrabbit Yes I have put in some breakpoints and it seems to be making its way thru the maze successfully until the abrupt termination

Comment: As you are new to coding, I just wanted to make this side-note.  In your loop, you set `i = -1`.  Unless there is a reason your loop needs to start there, you should start it at `0` like everyone else does.  I am guessing you did it so your arithmetic would work out in the next two lines.  To fix this, simply make those lines use `lastMove + i - 1`.  This way, your loop starts at 0, and your arithmetic stays correct.  (You will probably also have to change your loops limit to 3)

Comment: What does the console say? You wrote that it "terminates abnormally".

Comment: Thanks Jordan. The reason it starts at -1 is just because the way my modular arithmetic works: the algorithm tests what the last move you made was and tries the one to the right of it first, then straight etc., counterclockwise. This should not cause any problems? I could of course start i at 0 and replace with the expression i - 1.

Comment: @ Grzegorz: the console disappears. I would expect it to either be in an infinite loop or terminate with the usual "Press any key to continue..."

Comment: @ CM Kanode thanks, I will look up how to do that & try it.

Comment: @OliKlima  In the code that we can see, replacing the expression with `i - 1` would cause no issues.  If there is more code which depends on `i` in this loop, then it might not be worth it to spend a bunch of brain power just so that the loop starts at `0`.  It is not critical for the loop to start at `0`, just far more common, which generally translates into more readable.

Comment: @ Jordan, yes I can easily do that, thanks.

Comment: What prevents your algorithm from recursively going in circles in the maze? That's undoubtedly what's happening.

Comment: @ Taylor, I am not sure that's what's happening. Was trying to test that, but surprised it ended so quickly. The algorithm aims to recreate keeping your right hand on the maze wall at all times, which will get you out eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies all, and thank you for your responses.

After more debugging I have found the answer to my question, and it is nothing to do with a stack overflow.

It was because I assumed that the C++ operator % works like the mathematical version of modular arithmetic, outputting only 0,1,...,n-1 (mod n).

When I realised that this is not the case ( -1 % 4 is -1, and not 3) I was able to modify my code to make the algorithm work correctly.

Thanks for all the help!